# multiple select box jquery and post serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to to send a form via post but my multiple select box isn't being sent. How can I serialize the select box with the rest of the form and send it?

Here is the javascript I am using

```
$('#form-to-submit').empty().append($(fieldsetName).clone());

           $('#form-to-submit select').val($('.fieldsetwrapper select').val());
            var data = $('#form-to-submit').serialize();

            $.post(url,{data,function(data,textStatus){
```

I get all fields but the select in the post data.

Comment: I'm confused by your code sample. What are you trying to do? Send all the values in a form? Send just the value of the `select` box? Why are you cloning the form? What is `fieldsetName`?

Comment: It's hard to tell... why are you removing the contents of #form-to-submit?  I would alert($('#form-to-submit select').length) after your empty() call to see if the element exists at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The select will only serialize if there are selections made... see

Here is an example with serialization and jsonification
http://jsfiddle.net/XW2Cm/1/

Comment: Wow it took me so long to find this answer. Works great!

Comment: face palm moment